# TL494 dynamic frequency changing

Tags: pwm, frequency, tl494

I am using a TL494. I can adjust the duty cycle whenever I want, but I am having trouble changing the frequency.

The [TL494 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1625717309441&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.datasheet.ru%252Fsearch.html%253Fcx%253D005338834574777012439%253Aqye0jsmt8tw%2526cof%253DFORID%253A11%2526q%253DTL494%2526ie%253Dwindows-1251%2526sa%253D%2B%25EF%25BF%25BD%25EF%25BF%25BD%25EF%25BF%25BD%25EF%25BF%25BD%25EF%25BF%25BD%2B) says that the IC is a fixed-frequency PWM control IC.

I use push-pull operation so frequency formula is:

[image]

I want to use a button and dynamically change the frequency while the circuit is working. I can use a microprocessor to do it. I just could not put everything together in my mind. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The frequency is set by the resistor and capacitor. To change it you'd have to change one or both of those.

Comment: 1) What determines the frequency ? (hint: see that formula) So what options do you have? 2) A microprocessor to do **what**? An MCU isn't a magical / universal device. The MCU is **completely irrelevant** until you know **HOW** you will change the frequency of the PWM controller. 3) Suppose you have two identical components and a toggle switch, is there a way to make one component from that with a changable (switchable) value? 4) Now use that switchable component in the TL494's circuit (not how I didn't use an MCU).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's allowed to use an externally-generated pulse.

One thing you could do, for different frequencies, is to use separate resistors and/or capacitors that are activated/deactivated by MOSFETs controlled by the MCU:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC5IJF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remember that this method may require a lot of GPIOs.